# Cannot highlight the nav menu on current page in Antd menu component

Tags: reactjs, menu, next.js, antd, highlight

I'm trying to highlight the nav-menu item on the page I currently am with ant design Menu commponent. But it turns out that whichever page I'm on, the menu doesnt get highlighted. Here's my code for the nav menu.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Link from "next/link"
import { Layout, Menu } from "antd";
import styles from "./sidenav.module.css"

const { Sider } = Layout;


const SideNav = () => {
    const [key, setKey] = useState("");

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        setKey(e.key)
    }

    return (
        <Sider collapsible>
            <Menu className="menu-item"
                onClick={handleClick}
                defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
                selectedKeys={[key]}
                selectable={true}
                mode="inline" >

                <Menu.Item key="1" icon=""><Link href="/"><a>Home</a></Link></Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="2" icon=""><Link href="/about"><a>About me</a></Link></Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="3" icon=""><Link href="/team"><a>Team</a></Link></Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="4" icon=""><Link href="/blog"><a>Blog</a></Link></Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
        </Sider>
    )

}

export default SideNav;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on ant documentation for Menu, `onClick` function provides these props `{ item, key, keyPath, domEvent }`. You need some adjustments to your implementation of `handleClick`:

```
const SideNav = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState("");

  const handleClick = ({ _item, key, _keyPath, _domEvent }) => {
    console.log(key);
    setKey(key);
  };

  return (
    <Sider collapsible>
      <Menu
        className="menu-item"
        defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
        onClick={handleClick}
        selectedKeys={[key]}
        selectable={true}
        mode="inline"
      >
        <Menu.Item key="1" icon="">
          <Link href="/">
            <a>Home</a>
          </Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="2" icon="">
          <Link href="/about">
            <a>About me</a>
          </Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="3" icon="">
          <Link href="/team">
            <a>Team</a>
          </Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="4" icon="">
          <Link href="/blog">
            <a>Blog</a>
          </Link>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    </Sider>
  );
};
```

Please give this a try and let me know if it doesn't work as it should, explain the issue and I will update my answer accordingly.